# show pop up when is mouse over image control

Tags: wpf, image, wpf-controls, popup

I would like show pop up when is mouse over the image control.  So I create control template, it look like this:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="AvatarImageTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <HERE I WANT IMAGE SOURCE  Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Popup  IsOpen="False" 
                            Name="OponentImagePopUp"                               
                            AllowsTransparency="True"
                            PopupAnimation="Slide"
                            HorizontalOffset="-35"
                            VerticalOffset="0"
                            Grid.Row="1">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" 
                                BorderBrush="Black">
                        <Grid  Height="350" MinWidth="350">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,0.3">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Border BorderThickness="1" 
                                    BorderBrush="Black"
                                    Background="White"
                                    Margin="4,4,4,4"
                                    Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                    <Image.Source >
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource avatarConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="ProfilePhoto"></Binding>
                                            <Binding Path="StatusInfo.IsLogged"></Binding>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="OponentImagePopUp" Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

I have two problems:

1. I don’t how can I acces to image source in control template
2. Also If I try make a style on Image control and set property Template -> Image control don’t have a property template.

My aim is show pop pop window with same image only bigger.

**EDIT:**

I create simple control, as advice Mr. Glazkov, which have image control, here is it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Spirit.Controls.AvatarImageControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="SmallImage"
            Source="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ImageSource}"
            Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind is the same:

```
  public partial class AvatarImageControl : UserControl
    {
        public AvatarImageControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AvatarImageControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    }
```

I try use this contol in view:

```
<Grid Background="#99CCFF"  Margin="4,4,4,4">
      <Controls:AvatarImageControl ImageSource="{Binding Path=Oponent.Info.ProfilePhoto,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

I bind property type of Uri to ImageSource of AvatarImageControl.

What I do bad?

Also I try this in user control:

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="SmallImage"
        Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Stretch="Fill"/>
</Grid>
```

Result is same.

I use user control in view, I bind on ImageSource property property from view model type of Uri. Nothing else.

**EDIT 2:**
Code of Mr. Glazkov produce exception:

```
{"Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.IsOpen' threw an exception."}
{"A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'IsMouseOver' of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image'."}
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Spirit.Controls.AvatarImageControl.InitializeComponent() in c:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BACKUP\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0\Controls\AvatarImageControl.xaml:line 1
   at Spirit.Controls.AvatarImageControl..ctor() in C:\Users\Jan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BACKUP\Pokec__Messenger\Spirit_Caliburn_Micro_v1.0\Controls\AvatarImageControl.xaml.cs:line 24
```

Solution is :

```
 <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=SmallImage, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Set binding mode  on oneway.

It works good.

Thank Mr. Glazkov for help.

Comment: You forgot to specify name in your UserControl (see line 4 in my answer): x:Name="root"

Comment: Oki, I repair this one problem yet.

Comment: Yeah, forgot the binding mode... Updated my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot define a control template for the image control because it is not derived from `Control`, thus it doesn't have a control template. It just renders itself in the OnRender method.

What you can do is to create a User Control with one dependency property `ImageSource`. Here is the XAML of this control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AvatarImage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="root">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image x:Name="SmallImage"
               Source="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=ImageSource}"
               Grid.Row="0" />
        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=SmallImage, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               Name="OponentImagePopUp"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               PopupAnimation="Slide"
               HorizontalOffset="-35"
               VerticalOffset="0"
               Grid.Row="1">
            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Black">
                <Grid Height="350"
                      MinWidth="350">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                             EndPoint="0,0.3">
                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray"
                                              Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke"
                                              Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            Background="White"
                            Margin="4,4,4,4"
                            Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image Margin="2,2,2,2">
                            <Image.Source>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource avatarConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="ProfilePhoto"></Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="StatusInfo.IsLogged"></Binding>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the code behind (AvatarImage.xaml.cs):

```
public partial class AvatarImage : UserControl
{
    public AvatarImage() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AvatarImage), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Comment: Gj, nice and complete answer, was going to suggest a UserControl as well.

Comment: Mr. Glazkov I try your solution but I don’t know what I do bad, I don’t see any user control with image in my view.

Comment: Please see my comment on your post. Also will repeat it here: "You forgot to specify name in your UserControl (see line 4 in my answer): x:Name="root""

Comment: Thank, I didn’t notice, sorry. Also I don’t but I get same code as you a if a try open window with this control a I get error:  {Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.}

Comment: The error is very generic. Could you post more details? Inner exceptions, where the error happens, etc.

Answer (score 4):

A general approach to this:

```
    <CONTROL>
        <Grid>
            <!-- Actual control content -->
            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CONTROL}, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay}">
                <!-- Popup content -->
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </CONTROL>
```

You can access the image source via RelativeSource-binding as well, you just search for the ancestor type Image.

Edit: Now that your question is cleaned up a bit i can try to find some code for your two specific problems..
Edit2: Too slow...