# How to make the image pop-up on mouse hovering in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, triggers

how do I make a picture that will pop up when mouse hovering over a icon [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwcQn.png)

the xaml code for my icon

```
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="157,257,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="26" Source="img/info.png" Cursor="Hand">
                        <Image.OpacityMask>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="img/info.png"/>
                        </Image.OpacityMask>
                    </Image>
```

Comment: Using a Popup might do the trick see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735395/show-pop-up-when-is-mouse-over-image-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you use a Tootip over the icon

```
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="157,257,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="26" Source="img/info.png" Cursor="Hand">
            <Image.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="img/info.png"/>
            </Image.OpacityMask>
            <Image.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Placement="Bottom">
                    <ToolTip.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Path Margin="34,0,0,0" Fill="#e5AAAAAA" Data="M 0 16 L 16 0 L 32 16 Z"/>
                                <Image Height="100" Width="80" Source="img/bigImage.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ToolTip.Template>
                </ToolTip>
            </Image.ToolTip>
        </Image>
```

Comment: that was exactly what ive been looking for

Comment: but i got a strange problem with one of the tooltips when i place the image(trigger for it) under the middle of the form then the tooltip will only being showed in the top of the form and not under the image

Answer (score 2):

You can use WPF `Image.Style` `Trigger` to change the image source from, e.g. `img1.png` to `img2.png` on MouseOver event as shown in the following sample:

*Listing 1. Toggle images on Mouse Over in WPF Image control using Trigger*

```
<Image>
  <Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
      <Setter Property="Source" Value="img/img1.png"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Source" Value="img/img2.png"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Or, you may display the image `img/info.png` on MouseOver event using WPF`Trigger` to change the `Opacity` property from 0 to 1 (or using custom numbers pertinent to your case, e.g. from 0.2 to 1) as shown below:

*Listing 2. Display image on Mouse Over in WPF Image control using Trigger*

```
   <Image >
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="img/Cube.jpg"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

Important: DO NOT set the static image source as in your original code:

`<Image x:Name="image" Source="img/info.png"` .....

Instead, use the `Setter` as shown in the samples. Also, you do not need opacity mask to achieve this simple effect.

Hope this may help.

Comment: is not working with this `<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" Margin="157,257,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="26" Source="img/info.png" Cursor="Hand">
<Image.OpacityMask>
 <ImageBrush ImageSource="img/info.png"/>
 </Image.OpacityMask>
 <Image.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Source" Value="img/Profilhøjde.jpg"/>
 </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Image.Style>
</Image>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Event `UIElement.MouseEnter` and `UIElement.MouseLeave` to change the `UIElement.Visibility` from `Visibility.Collapsed` to `Visibility.Visible` of the `ImageControl`.

Or you use Trigger

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Styles.StyleTriggersSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="StyleTriggersSample" Height="100" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, styled world!" FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Source: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your xaml as a custom tooltip - see [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/creating-fancy-tooltips-in-wpf/)